# when is it necessary or when should a controller be async

Tags: c#, async, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-web-api

When is it absolutely necessary for a controller to be async? Should all controllers be async or is it bad practice to make all of them async unless it is necessary. 
Just looking for some general guidelines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's *never* absolutely necessary for a controller to be async. Calls to controller methods will *eventually* return.  However, it might be desirable to hand off a long-running task to a thread, so that the web server is not blocked for a long period of time.

I wouldn't bother making *every* controller asynchronous.  There is some overhead involved in creating new threads; making every controller asynchronous might actually slow things down.

> Use asynchronous action methods for long-running, non-CPU bound
>   requests. This avoids blocking the Web server from performing work
>   while the request is being processed. A typical use for the
>   AsyncController class is long-running Web service calls.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: "However, it might be desirable to hand off a long-running task to a thread" - I actually would prefer to create some explicit mechanism for a worker thread or some parallel routine instead of just `async`hronously exiting the controller method and then hoping that my long-running task will be finished, and I can later check the results (most probably, launching a new web request, since the original has already returned, if it was truly async)

Comment: Would the "long-running, non-CPU bound requests" include database calls?  Basically every call in my web app has database calls.

Comment: Yes, if those database calls are long-running.   All of the CPU time takes place on the database server.