# Is there a standard name (or examples) for the "sandwich" pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, naming, patterns-and-practices

I've noticed a certain idea recur in different contexts, but before I start calling it "the sandwich pattern", it would be useful to know (in the spirit of other ["Is there a name for this pattern?" questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?tab=Relevance&q=is%20there%20a%20name%20for%20this%20pattern) on this site):

1. whether it is a recognized concept that already has a better-known name, and
2. whether there are further examples to illustrate this pattern.

What I'm thinking of as "the sandwich pattern" is abstracted from a couple of examples:

1. The first is Ned Batchelder's ["Pragmatic Unicode"](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) from 2012, where he suggests a "Unicode sandwich": [emphasis added]

   > the data coming into and going out of your program must be bytes. But you don’t need to deal with bytes on the inside of your program. The best strategy is to decode incoming bytes *as soon as possible*, producing unicode. You use unicode throughout your program, and then when outputting data, encode it to bytes *as late as possible*. This creates a **Unicode sandwich**: bytes on the outside, Unicode on the inside.

   The name is repeated at the end, as one of the three main take-aways:

   > Unicode sandwich: keep all text in your program as Unicode, and convert *as close to the edges as possible*.
2. The example that motivates this question. At work, we have a system (program) that (among other things) happens to deal with dates, and a date can differ depending on whether it is in:

   - the customer's timezone, or
   - what I'll call the "global timezone", for simplicity. (Don't worry about the fact that different machines can differ in their timezone; it's not relevant here and if you prefer you can think of it as UTC… that's not the point of this question.)

   The code can get a bit confusing and error-prone for this reason, converting dates between timezones here and there, but it turns out that much of the business logic of this system is concerned with the customer timezone, so I'm thinking about the following proposal:

   - Establish the convention (enforced with types if necessary; that's a separate discussion) that the "customer timezone" is used everywhere in the code, i.e. a date means the date in the customer timezone by default, except:
   - at certain boundaries, where it is necessary to interact with the "global timezone", we immediately convert either from the global timezone to customer timezone (when the date comes from the external system), or from customer timezone to the global timezone (when the date needs to be written out to the external system).

   That is, a "sandwich" with global timezone on the outside, and customer timezone on the inside.

Both these examples appear to me to be instances of a single, more general pattern, something like [this is not a quotation, just my attempt to put the pattern in words]:

> Sometimes, there can be multiple kinds of the same "thing" (like "bytes" and "unicode" in (1), or "global date" and "customer date" in (2)) that tend to be used in similar contexts / have some semantic overlap.
>
> To avoid error, confusion, and too much back-and-forth conversion between the two kinds of "thing", it helps to have a convention where you:
>
> - identify the preferred kind, and
> - design your system such that "things" *inside* the system are of the preferred kind, and conversion happens as close as possible to the boundaries with whichever external systems require the other kind.

(But maybe the pattern is even more general; see the "Aside" later below.)

This pattern seems a "design pattern" at least in the broader sense of "a general, reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem within a given context" (the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Software_design_pattern&oldid=1024267680) lede), even if not in the narrow sense of the original object-oriented design patterns from the "Gang of Four" book (e.g. consider that the book [Game Programming Patterns](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/) includes "patterns" like ["data locality"](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/data-locality.html#the-pattern)). But in any case, my question is **not** about whether this qualifies as a "design pattern", but about the "sandwich" software-engineering idea/principle/pattern itself: specifically, whether there are existing names (and other examples) for it.

---

**Aside**: That's the question, but it's possible that the two examples above, and the common pattern I abstracted from them, are not at the right level of generality/abstraction, because perhaps the following examples can also be folded under the same pattern:

3. Also from 2012 is Gary Bernhardt's ["Functional Core, Imperative Shell"](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts/catalog/functional-core-imperative-shell) idea. It is also mentioned in his ["Boundaries"](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/boundaries) talk ([YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOYal8elnZk)), and [searching this site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22functional%20core%22%20%22imperative%20shell%22) finds several mentions. Roughly, the idea is to have impure functions only on the "outside" (the "shell") and have "pure" functions in the "core" (more links [here](https://github.com/kbilsted/Functional-core-imperative-shell/blob/master/README.md)).
4. Not an independent example, but [an answer on this site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/396111/3220) by user Theraot, taking inspiration from "the idea of a pure core and an impure shell", suggests a similar idea for `async` functions:

   > interacting with external systems is often `async` […] The solutions is that the entry point will be impure (and `async`) it will deal with external systems (impure imperative shell) and call into your not `async` code (pure functional core), which returns to the shell for more interoperability. That way you do not have to make everything `async`, and you do not have to make your whole code impure.

These examples are different in some ways from the "sandwich pattern" as in the actual question above the line: The conversion only goes one way; there's no straightforward way to convert an impure function to pure, or async function to sync. It's not like there's a risk of accidentally using the "incorrect" kind of function (and we're less worried about the reader getting confused which is which), so the problem being solved is entirely different. But what's similar is the idea of consciously choosing to declare one kind as preferable, and carefully designing such that this kind is used everywhere in the "core" except a "shell" where forced otherwise by external boundaries. A supporting coincidence(?) is that a search just before asking this question led me to Mark Seemann's 2020 post ["Impureim sandwich"](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2020/03/02/impureim-sandwich/), where (apparently independently) he comes up with the term "sandwich" for this pattern.

Comment: I'm somewhat reminded of Common Lisp's method combinations—if you aren't already familiar, I'd recommend [this chapter from *Practical Common Lisp*](https://gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-generic-functions.html). The concept is similar to "advice" in Emacs. (And Common Lisp got it from Lisp Machine Lisp, which got the idea from the advice feature in Interlisp.) You can define "before", "after", and "around" methods to implement the sandwich.

Comment: For instance, you might define a method `(process-datum (thing canonical-form))` that does important stuff to a specific form of information. Then you might have methods `(process-datum (thing degenerate-form-1))`, `(process-datum (thing degenerate-form-2))`, etc., which convert the degenerate forms into the canonical form before handing them to the main `process-datum` method. If these auxiliary methods are defined as `:before` the main one, then you might also have corresponding `:after` methods to convert back to the original form once processing has concluded.

Comment: I think that Python's decorators might (be able to) serve a similar purpose to the method combination, although I'm not familiar enough with the language to say so definitively.

Comment: @texdr.aft Nice to see you here. :-) I don't yet very clearly see the connection to the method combinations you mentioned, but about your last comment, yes Python decorators can be used for a roughly similar purpose as the link you pointed to, though in Python a decorator like `@d` before a `def f:` is simply shorthand for replacing `f` with `g(f)` (see [this](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/) say), so it can be arbitrary code and there's no special marker or convention for before, after, around etc.

Comment: I've edited the question ([revision 5](/posts/426816/revisions)) in response to 2 close votes as "opinion-based" (*"This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers"*); hope it's better. Of the two answers so far, one gives 2 further examples and an existing name for a related/overlapping pattern (the kind of fact-based answer I'm seeking); the earliest answer (based on revision 2) may have made the question seem "opinion-based" (which it probably was!) but was very helpful to improve the question.

Comment: The idea that you translate something to an internal format on the way in and back to an external format on the way out is called “encapsulation.” You are essentially hiding the internal format from the rest of the world. Encapsulation is an important part of many design patterns, not a design pattern unto itself.

Comment: @JohnWu Interesting, I can see a connection, but would you call, say, the Python "Unicode sandwich" an example of encapsulation? Both `bytes` and unicode (`str`) are built-in standard types in Python (there's no "hiding the internal format" going on), and the crux of the pattern IMO is simply *deciding* that one of them should be an "internal format" and the other solely an "external format" to be used as less as possible. (Similarly with the dates example, and the array index example below.) One *could* implement any of those three examples with types or a class hierarchy (contd…)

Comment: @JohnWu (e.g. for the array index example, using types called say IndexExternal and IndexInternal, instead of plain integers), but we get most of the benefit even from adopting it as a convention. In some sense, the main thing about the pattern is to **ask yourself** whether, of two kinds of things that seem to be at the same level, one of them can be preferred internally to the extent that the other can be restricted to being solely "an external format" as you say. The resulting insight is something that is obvious in retrospect, but the "pattern" is to prompt the question that leads to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Canonical Form

Or, as I've heard folks calling it more casually: a canonical representation. This is a [term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization) derived from math.

> In computer science, canonicalization (sometimes standardization or normalization) is a process for converting data that has more than one possible representation into a "standard", "normal", or canonical form. This can be done to compare different representations for equivalence, to count the number of distinct data structures, to improve the efficiency of various algorithms by eliminating repeated calculations, or to make it possible to impose a meaningful sorting order.

Now, this may not seem too relevant, but only because the language of math is highly abstract. (And that's why I've quoted more CS-related term rather that the original.) But, consider the following not immediately obvious implications:

- **Loss-less.** Canonical form is a loss-less representation. It may serve as an intermediate for converting between other representations of the same kind.

  For example, Unicode is a super-set of many other encodings.
- **Arbitrary.** Sometimes there are many equally good alternatives for the role of a canonical form. One may be chosen anyways, just for sake of standardization.

  In your example, customer's time zone was agreed upon, not because it's a better format, but because it's more prevalent in the code base <sup><sup>(my guess)</sup></sup>, allowing the developers to spend less brain juice on validating their assumptions.
- **Conventional**. The name itself suggests that a canonical form is a some sort of a standard (especially so if you'd call it a *standard* form), potentially making a convention more agreeable.
- **Contextual.** Is SE, we often re-use and override concepts in different contexts. There is no global canonical form for a given kind of data, so you are free to declare your own standards in the scope that you own.

  You'd think something like Unicode should have a predefined canonical form, but an Unicode handling library may represent it differently under the hood, to improve performance or maintainability, and so that will be the canonical form for that library.

---

As a side note, I don't think that a sandwich is a good model for the given examples, because sandwich (as described) puts emphasis on crossing the boundaries. But we do boundaries all day every day: APIs, data hiding in OOP, namespaces, modules, domains, packages, etc. There's nothing special about this, besides boundaries being boundaries.

Rather, the crux is in the meaty part of the sandwich: establishing a certain data format/structure to be a standard way of working with a given kind of data. Which is similar to what you've described with you own words. Without a standard, the middle layer of that sandwich would be a salad of different formats and conversions between them.

Comment: The term "round-trip conversion" might be relevant, although the idea is covered by the requirement that the change in representation must be lossless.

Comment: Thanks, it seems obvious in hindsight but you're right that the heart of the pattern seems to be "establishing a certain data format/structure to be a standard way" (to be used as much as possible). Indeed, in all the three best examples so far (unicode, dates, array indexes) we can say that the main thing going on is the *recognition* of a certain kind as preferred/canonical. After this recognition (which is the nontrivial part), the attempt to use it wherever possible naturally leads to "everywhere except boundaries".

Answer (score 2):

You have given a large number of examples, in very unrelated areas of application design. Is there a pattern? I think in the broadest sense of the word "pattern" then, yes, there is a pattern. I don't think this qualifies as a software design pattern, because the problems in each example are different, and yet clearly there is a "pattern."

It is like fractals. Fractal patterns are common in nature, from the shapes of galaxies to the branches of trees, to the shapes of the veins in a leaf. Fractal patterns are *everywhere* but do not represent a single, general solution to a problem common to things of all shapes and sizes across time and space.

You have identified a very, very general pattern of one thing on the outside and another thing on the inside, but I'm afraid this does not fit the description of a Software Design Pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much; I've clarified the question a bit ([revision 3](/posts/426816/revisions)). (It's bad when questions are edited in a way to invalidate already-posted answers, but I hope that is not much the case here.) To be clear: • I had started with 3 examples in mind and while writing found another one I introduced as "Not an independent example", but I've changed indentation to make it 3 examples again. (And perhaps only two examples fit!) • I've added an explicit description of what I see as the pattern, a bit more than just "one thing on the outside and another thing on the inside".

Comment: I've been thinking about your "very unrelated areas of application design" and it's a good point: while the *solution* is similar both in 1/3 and in 2/2'—namely, use the "preferred" kind of thing inside wherever possible, and use the other kind only at boundaries where forced to do so by external systems—the *problem* is different: in (1) and (3) the goal is to increase clarity and avoid errors and unnecessary conversions, but in (2) and (2') one is typically not worried about accidentally using the wrong kind of function or converting between them unnecessarily; that's at best a side-benefit.

Comment: Unfortunately I ended up editing the question more substantially by reordering examples ([revision 5](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/426816/revisions), back to four examples again) as a couple of people thought the question was opinion-based, but this answer was very helpful to me to clarify the question (and more importantly, my thinking); thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I've applied this pattern in at least two other situations:

- External 1-based indexes, internal 0-based indexes.
- External a string containing JSON, internal an app-specific data structure.

I think it's fair to say this is more than a naturally-occurring phenomenon that's interesting to observe. It's something you can intentionally apply to improve the design of your code. In my mind that qualifies it as a design pattern, even though it may not be a well-known one.

For example, in my index case, there were conversions scattered throughout a fairly extensive code base. It caused frequent bugs. The one I was looking at that day was caused by accidentally applying a *2*-based index to a 0-based array, because one of the dozens of conversions had been done in the wrong direction. Applying the sandwich pattern essentially eliminated that class of bugs.

My second example I've also seen called [Parse, don't validate](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/), but the premise is the same. Use the safest, most consistent representation in as much of your code as possible, and convert it as needed on the boundaries.

Comment: Illuminating examples, thank you! I had encountered "Parse, don't validate" before, but hadn't made the connection. There is some overlap, and if I squint a bit I can kind of see both the unicode and date examples from the question and the "two kinds of array" above as instances of it ("parsing" into the preferred kind). But in cases like these, where the parsing (and in fact, conversion in *both* directions) is trivial (and therefore can be rampant in the code!), the emphasis suggested by "parse don't validate" seems more on just parsing/input so the "sandwich" idea seems good to have around.

Comment: I think many of us use these types of patterns, like graphics software that solely works with 32-bit SPFP images once imported to unify and simplify the data and code that works with it even though it can import and export a wide variety of image formats. Unicode is another example where the bulk of a codebase might work with, say, UTF-8 even though specific cases require it to convert to/from other encodings. My thinking for why these things aren't commonly referred to as design patterns with their own name is that this is data-oriented in terms of design.

Comment: A lot of the focus on popular design patterns seems to be object-oriented rather than data-oriented (which an object-oriented mindset would treat as an implementation rather than a design-level concern).

Comment: @DrunkRider Interesting; I would absolutely consider "Parse, don't validate" a design pattern, just as the author of "Impureim sandwich" (linked from the question) considers it a design pattern. It hadn't occurred to me that anyone wouldn't; neither of them is particularly object-oriented. (I mean, surely even if one is programming in a style that isn't object-oriented—say idiomatic functional programming in Haskell—one uses design patterns. I looked up [Game Programming Patterns](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/contents.html) and it contains data-oriented things like "Data Locality".)

Comment: I especially like the array indexes example. In the "JSON string vs internal data structure" case, the programmer is more likely to realize something is wrong if converting back and forth too much, and less likely to use the wrong kind by accident and cause subtle logic errors. But in the offset-by-one case, working with plain integers, the conversion (adding or subtracting 1) is so trivial that one may not even consider such a convention: it takes conscious intention to adopt it, and the results can be surprisingly good (eliminating a class of bugs, as this says).

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe, I go simply with "zone awareness" or "zone thinking". It sounds trivial at first, but IMO it is such a vital thing for every software developer.

I can extend your list with own examples, like Karl Bielefeld did:

- Data are available in XML, but later they are available as business objects, later again as XML or as HTML.
- Data are unsafe at first, later they are safe. This may concern simple details, e.g. data are safe to be not null or safe not to have malicious attack values included.
- Data are raw at first, later they contain highlight markup information coming from a search entry. You do not want to store data with highlight markup information into the model table. You need zones.
- Activity start and end times are raw and not rounded at first, but later they are rounded e.g. to five minutes and flattened (no parallel times). The rounding and flattening algorithm may be complex.

What I am saying is that I do not search a pattern name for this, but I recognize the importance of zones and try to stick to the following rules:

1. Define clear zones.

Make sure every piece of code inside a zone expects and delivers compliant data. Once you have zones, e.g. call graphs will be easier understand.

2. Make sure your data go from one zone into another only by a clear defined (and tested) way.

That may be a big conversion class, but it might also be a simple, tiny convention by which you have variable names with the prefix "safe" for data that are safe. Every usage of not "safe" data in certain places are red flags.

If I remember correct, I encountered the word "zone" the first time with clear awareness in an article about writing secure code. Now in your article we read "Sandwich", which is creative and a good picture. I'll stay with "zones".

Comment: Thank you; this is clearly relevant and I guess it's inevitable that there will be overlapping ideas (thanks for pointing this out), but I think what makes the "sandwich" I described less broad than these "zones" in general, is the principle that although it is easy to have many zones, one gets better results if you design your systems by recognizing that one zone is "preferred", and are careful to make it as large as possible, such that there are exactly *two* zones: an "outside" (specifically, boundaries with external systems) and an "inside" (everything else).

Comment: That is, I think you're very right that the problems in both the "sandwich" examples I gave (unicode, and dates) can *also* be solved by being very careful and conscious and aware of what type of data you have at each point/zone in your code (and this is an important principle in general, e.g. for security)—e.g. annotate each Python function with whether it accepts bytes or unicode, or add type-checking—but I also feel this is a *different* (though clearly overlapping) solution to the problem than the main "sandwich" idea of consciously forcing the "inner zone" to be as large as possible.